# Can ordinal definability be defined using no more than one ordinal parameter?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, definability

This [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449629/95347) shows that one can indeed define ordinal definable this way:

$\begin{align} \textbf{Define: }  & \operatorname {OD} (X) \iff \\& \exists \theta \, \exists \varphi: X= \{y \in V_\theta \mid V_\theta \models \varphi(y)\}\end{align}$

Here, we further attempt to get ride of $\theta$ above, and have maximally one ordinal parameter that is the code for the defining predicate $\varphi$ itself.

Being a level of the cumulative hierarchy, usually defined by being $V_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, can be defined without any mention of ordinals whatsoever.

I'll use [Scott-Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Potter_set_theory#Preliminaries) set theory terminology, were $\operatorname {level}$ is defined as an **accumulation** $``acc"$ of a **history**, as follows:

$\textbf{Define: } acc(a) = \{ x \mid \exists b \in a \, (x \in b \lor x \subseteq b) \} \\ \textbf{Define: } \operatorname {history} (V) \iff \forall v \in V : v=acc(v \cap V) \\ \textbf{Define: } \operatorname {level}(v) \iff \exists V: \operatorname {history}(V) \land v=acc(V) $

$ \begin{align} \textbf{Define: }  & V \text { is min-level over } \varphi \iff \\ & \operatorname {level} (V) \ \land \\ & \forall z \, (\varphi(z) \to V \models \varphi(z)) \ \land \\ &\forall \operatorname {level} W [\forall z \, (\varphi(z) \to W \models \varphi(z)) \to V \subseteq W] \end{align}$

$ \textbf{Define: } \\ \begin{align}  \operatorname {OD} (X) \iff  \exists \varphi: X= \{y \mid  \exists  V &:    V \text{ is min-level over } \varphi \ \\ & \land y \in V \land  [V \models \varphi(y)]\}\end{align} $

> Is this an equivalent definition of ordinal definability?

This way we have only one parameter that is $\varphi$ which is usually formalized as an ordinal, however in the context of definability most of the time the predicate symbol is not included among parameters of the definition, so if as a terminology we restrict the term *parameter* to only the free variables in the defining formula other than the set builder variable and of course other than the predicate symbol or whatever coding for that predicate is used, then this reduces ordinal definability to virtually parameter free definability, and so $\sf HOD$ is reducible conceptually to $\sf HD$ since *definable* when put alone is usually taken to mean parameter free definable. This in some sense is the feeling one gets from the [equivalence of $\sf V=HOD$ with the parameter free definability rule](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448130/are-all-constructible-from-below-sets-parameter-free-definable/448132#448132), over the rest of axioms of $\sf ZFC$, which is further supported by [infinitary $\sf ZF + Def$ being just a conservative extension of $\sf ZFC + Definability \ rule $](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449700/95347). However, if as shown in [that answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449629/95347), one must treat $\varphi$ as a parameter, then we'd have ordinal definability defined using only ONE ordinal parameter.